# composer lib local unpushed commit status

Tags: php, git, workflow, composer-php

I'm working on a php composer lib. I make some local commits on the lib but don't push them. Then I use composer update to fetch updated commits from other people, and my local commits disappear. Is there any way i can check for local unpushed commits, similar to what composer status does, but not just for uncommitted changes?

Comment: I think you should use git instead of composer here. you then can sync with other (decentralized) repositories and also merge so that your local changes do not get lost. So checkout the lib under git, not under composer. Composer is only to install existing packages - not to modify them. If you then want to use your development version instead of the original lib, override it in your composer.json where you want to use that lib. -- http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md -- http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories (wors with local git repoes as well).

Comment: You'll probably be better off forking the library you're wanting to change, and then include your forked version via. composer instead. This is especially easy to do if the lib is on Github.